# Finding index of maximum value in array with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I would like to find a maximum in a `float64` array, excluding `nan` values.

I saw `np.nanmax` function but it doesn't give the index corresponding to the found value.

it 's quite strange to scan after to the value specially the function necessarily use the index ??? Can't it be a mistake searching like that .

isn't there a way to recover the index directly ?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Numpy has an `argmax` function that returns just that, although you will have to deal with the `nan`s manually. `nan`s always get sorted to the end of an array, so with that in mind you can do:

```
a = np.random.rand(10000)
a[np.random.randint(10000, size=(10,))] = np.nan
a = a.reshape(100, 100)

def nanargmax(a):
    idx = np.argmax(a, axis=None)
    multi_idx = np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape)
    if np.isnan(a[multi_idx]):
        nan_count = np.sum(np.isnan(a))
        # In numpy < 1.8 use idx = np.argsort(a, axis=None)[-nan_count-1]
        idx = np.argpartition(a, -nan_count-1, axis=None)[-nan_count-1]
        multi_idx = np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape)
    return multi_idx

>>> nanargmax(a)
(20, 93)
```

Comment: An off-by-one error, was looking at the first nan, not the last non-nan, should work after the edit above.

Comment: Actually, I just checked, and numpy has a [`np.nanargmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanargmax.html) which is probably what you should be using.

Comment: @Jaime np.nanargmax is exactly right, that's what I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25192626/2098573

Answer (score 8):

You should use `np.where`

```
In [17]: a=np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=10)

In [18]: a
Out[18]: 
array([ 1.43249468,  4.93950873,  7.22094395,  1.20248629,  4.66783985,
        6.17578054,  4.6542771 ,  7.09244492,  7.58580515,  5.72501954])

In [20]: np.where(a==a.max())
Out[20]: (array([8]),)
```

This also works for 2 arrays, the returned value, is the index. 
Here we create a range from 1 to 9:

```
 x = np.arange(9.).reshape(3, 3)
```

This returns the index, of the the items that equal 5:

```
In [34]: np.where(x == 5)
Out[34]: (array([1]), array([2])) # the first one is the row index, the second is the column
```

You can use this value directly to slice your array:

```
In [35]: x[np.where(x == 5)]
Out[35]: array([ 5.])
```

Comment: Sorry i'm beginner and then how to get indexes in case of 1D or 2D array

Comment: This is great but how can we find the max per column?  e.g. x = np.arange(9.).reshape(3, 3);x.min(1)

Comment: Apply np.where to each column.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [numpy.nanargmax](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanargmax.html)

The documentation provides some clear examples.

```
a = np.array([[np.nan, 4], [2, 3]])
print np.argmax(a)
0

print np.nanargmax(a)
1

np.nanargmax(a, axis=0)
array([1, 0])

np.nanargmax(a, axis=1)
array([1, 1])
```